# First day of last 3 weeks and first day of last 3 months

Tags: php

Am trying to calculate the first day of last 3 weeks and first day of last 3 months in unix timestamp in PHP.

I know I have to use date function but am a bit lost. I do not have PHP 5.3 thus I cannot use relative formats.

Am using the above to decide whether or not to delete a backup. e.g.

```
if ($time > time()-3600*24*7 && $time < time()) {
    echo "Keeping: $file<br/>";
}
```

I want to keep backups for:

1. Last 7 days
2. First day of last 3 weeks
3. First day of last 3 months

Am trying to calculate the first day of last 3 weeks and first day of last 3 months in unix timestamp in PHP.

I know I have to use date function but am a bit lost. I do not have PHP 5.3 thus I cannot use relative formats.

Am using the above to decide whether or not to delete a backup. e.g.

```
if ($time > time()-3600*24*7 && $time < time()) {
    echo "Keeping: $file<br/>";
}
```

I want to keep backups for:

1. Last 7 days
2. First day of last 3 weeks
3. First day of last 3 months

Update

Adding the solution, as I figured it out with the help of Pekka

```
$a = (strtotime("last Monday-1 week"));
$b = (strtotime("last Monday-2 week"));
$c = (strtotime("last Monday-3 week"));
$d = (strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));
$e = (strtotime('-1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00')));
$f = (strtotime('-2 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00')));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://en.php.net/strtotime)'s magic.

```
echo strtotime("-7 days");
echo strtotime("-3 weeks");
echo strtotime("-3 months");
```

strtotime() can even do stuff like `last tuesday`, `midnight`.....

Comment: date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',strtotime("-1 month")) gives 16th Jan. But I want 1st of Jan. Any idea?

Comment: @Alec amazingly, `strtotime("first day of last month")` seems to work fine

Comment: @Alec it works for me on 5.3. This may depend on the OS more than the PHP version, as I think it calls the OS's strtotime() function (at least on Linux). In that case, you will need to use `mktime()` http://php.net/mktime with the month from the `-1 month` call

Answer (score 5):

I know this question quite old, but thought of sharing my own answer so that other people might find it useful. This worked in PHP 7.2 and not sure about other versions. To get first day of 3 months back, here is the code.

```
 echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("FIRST DAY OF -3 MONTH"));
```

result:

```
2021-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

To calculate dates you can use `strtotime`:

```
$last7days   = strtotime('-7 days');
$last3weeks  = strtotime('-3 weeks');
$last3months = strtotime('-3 months');
```

then simply compare it to `$time` value:

```
if ( $time > $last7days ) {
    ...
}
```